# Light-weight library for recurring billing using Clojure web stacks?

Tags: clojure, e-commerce, recurring-billing

I want to implement simple, light-weight recurring billing for a ring-based web app.

Here's what I found:

- clj-stripe for Stripe API, but this also means that I have to use stripe.com for payment management.
- Apache Ofbiz, a heavy, full-featured e-commerce framework that I can always inter-op with, but it's too heavy.
- shopify-clojure, a Shopify wrapper that stopped updating in 2013.

What's the recommended way for basic billing management in Clojure? Ideally something like ActiveMerchant in RoR.

Answer (score 5):

It is my *opinion* that recurring billing, if done well enough to satisfy customers, has enough of it's own inherent complexity that there will not be a library only solution. The best you can likely hope for is a high quality service that provides a lightweight interface.  **this is the classic build vs. buy decission** which is a bit too broad for a SO answer.

I strongly suspect that such a library does not exist independent from a larger project or service such as 3scale, stripe, or something you build in-house.